# Symfony2 + DoctrineFixtureBundle : .git/info/refs not found

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have a fatal error, when updating my current symfony 2 version (from 2.0.12 to 2.0.15).

Here the **error**:

```
> Installing/Updating doctrine-fixtures
HEAD is now at bed8908 Update README.md

> Installing/Updating DoctrineFixturesBundle
fatal: https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

PS: I have done the `git update-server-info` command. But nothing...

Here my **deps** file

```
[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git    

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

and my **deps.lock** file

```
doctrine-fixtures bed8908ae929562317e5c59dc0bee24f3b63067e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

- Thanks to previous answer, remove DoctrinerFixtureBundle into your repository
- Secondly, run `php bin/vendors reinstall`

The reinstall vendors will be the command which makes the difference into my case...

Comment: Try to run ./bin/vendors install --reinstall

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same thing today.

The key thing to note is that the issue relates to [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git) (note /symfony and not /doctrine)

If you check the [latest change](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/commit/479f10d068bd0b01e055aa2f555946893322b79c) to the 2.0 Branch you'll see they've changed it to point to the correct repository.

I had to end up deleting the `bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle` from my vendors directory and re-ran `php bin/vendors install`.

I can now run bin/vendors install without it throwing the fatal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your *deps* file.

Change:

```
[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

Into:

```
[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

Then, run:

```
bin/vendors install
```

It should install only missing bundles.